# Join or Union table with same Characteristics and different Measures

Tags: sql, select, union, coalesce, full-outer-join

I would like to understand the easy/better way to join 2 tables with same characteristics and different measures as an example described below:

tab1

| Col1 | Col2 | Measure1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

tab2

| Col1 | Col2 | Measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 |

Expected Result

| Col1 | Col2 | Measure1 | Measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 25 |

**Questions:**

- How to avoid message: Ambiguous column name col1?
- How to create a correct Join?

**I have tried:**

```
select col1, col2, t1.Measure1, t2.Measure2
from tab1 t1
full outer jon tab2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

I have tried a Union and it works, but i am looking a easy way using joins:

```
Select col1, col2, Measure1, 0 as Measure2 From tab1
Union
Select col1, col2, 0 as Measure1, Measure2 From tab2
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running : oracle, postgresql, sql-server...?

Comment: Please ask 1 question. Debug questions require a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `full join` is the correct approach. But you need to disambiguate `col1` and `col2` in the `select` clause: both tables have both columns, so it is unclear to which column an *unprefixed* `col1` refers.

A typical approach uses `coalesce()`:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) col1,
    coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col2) col2,
    coalesce(t1.measure1, 0) measure1, 
    coalesce(t2.measure2, 0) measure2
from tab1 t1
full outer jon tab2 t2 
    on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Note that you also need `coalesce()` around the measures to return `0` instead of `null` on "missing" values.

In some databases (eg Postgres), you can use the `using` syntax to declare the join conditions for columns that have the same name across the tables ; this syntax automagically disambiguates the unprefixed column names, so:

```
select 
    col1,
    col2,
    coalesce(t1.measure1, 0) measure1, 
    coalesce(t2.measure2, 0) measure2
from tab1 t1
full join tab2 t2 using (col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference source tables for `col1` and `col2` as well.

As you're using `FULL OUTER JOIN` I'd recommend using `COALESCE` statement.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       COALESCE(t1.col2, t2.col2) as col2, 
       t1.Measure1, 
       t2.Measure2
FROM tab1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN tab2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```